# How do I load images onto a cursor using async task?

Tags: java, android

I have this piece of code in the onCreate Method in my main activity.

```
// Getting the column we want
String[] projection = new String[]{MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

// create async task
LoadTask loadtask = new LoadTask();
loadtask.execute(projection);
```

And in the loadtask class I have this code

```
private class LoadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Cursor>
{
    @Override
    protected Cursor doInBackground(String... strings) {
        Cursor imageCursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                projection,
                null,
                null,
                MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_ADDED);
        return null;
    }
}
```

My aim is to load all the images from my phone onto the cursor which I will use. This ends up crashing and I cant understand why. I thought that running the code in an async task should not allow the app to freeze. Any help for an android beginner?

Comment: have you asked for permission approval in manifest and runtime?

Comment: Yes, I've already asked for permission in manifest, but not at runtime.

Comment: that might be the problem

Comment: Do you know how I can ask for runtime permission?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting